# tfs android not checking in

Tags: java, android, tfs, azure-devops

Using TFS in eclipse. And while checking in whole project this error occurs. I can check in seperate files.

> The local item 'D:\LUDev\Stalker\AndroidApp\gen\com\stalker\androidappa\BuildConfig.java' no longer exists. (The local item 'D:\LUDev\Stalker\AndroidApp\gen\com\stalker\androidappa\BuildConfig.java' no longer exists.)

I don't have `D:\LUDev\Stalker\AndroidApp\gen\com\stalker\androidappa...` this directory in my local as well as server directory.

Comment: Found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your server workspace has gotten out of sync from the server. This can happen when the files are edited outside of the tfs process locally. If you get latest with the "force" flag you should get back into sync.

Comment: I'll check it, then tell you

Comment: by the way, I have analyse that those files which I added in my project. And then deleted them without even checking them in are creating errors. I tried to check in res folder only, error arises saying about a picture which I have added then deleted right after next build.